# Determine the equation for this series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

A patient takes 50 mg of drug X at the same time every day. Just before each tablet is taken, 2% of the drug remains in the body.

I need to find what quantity of the drug will be in the patients body just after the third drug is taken.

And by figuring that out it should help me determine the quantity of the drug in the patient's body in the long run (just after a tablet is taken).

So we know each day 1 mg of the drug will still be in the patients body.

Day 1: 50mg

Day 2: 50mg + 1mg = 51mg

Day 3: 50mg + 1.02mg = 51.02mg

Day 4: 50mg + 1.0204mg = 51.0204mg

Day 5: 50mg + 1.020408mg = 51.020408mg

So according to my data after the third day the patient will have 51.02mg just after taking the pill for the day. The part that stumps me is how much will be in the patients body after the long run. It seems as if it will never get above 51.02 but I don't see a pattern, or at least a pattern that I could turn into a equation. I was thinking something like:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} 50+(k_{n-1}*.02)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like $50 + 50 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n 0.02^i$ should work.

Comment: So did I calculate each day wrong then, because for example when I plug in 2 for n, to represent the second day I get 52.02, and according to my data it will never get above 51

Comment: @Overclock fixed it.

Comment: Yes that does work I realized I should have took the 50 times 0.02 and made that its own sequence, instead of trying to do it all at once.